# Converting HTML page into image using URL

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am doing one project on django-platform.

I have one question to ask which I am finding it for long time  : 
Is there any method to convert html page like **www.google.com**  that convert into image directly and save in project directory.

I need to write code to do this.
Let's have a url (say :

```
/employee/{emp_code}/certificate/{id}/download
```

) . On hitting this URL , This should convert into image.

EDITED :

Simply I want to implement this : http://www.verypdf.com/online/url-to-image-converter.php

http://www.page2images.com/free_convert_website_url_to_images_in_batch

Comment: Here is a solution from stack overflow from years ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645/take-a-screenshot-via-a-python-script-linux

Comment: But this is not using url given...  I need image of that URL Html

Comment: Personally I would use a tool like phantomjs which can easily grab and save screenshots.  It's much faster than Selenium.  If you decide to go that route checkout that casperjs project that coincides with phantom.  You can just fire the script for phantom from python.  Maybe somebody knows of a better tool for this type of thing.