# Import QApplication fails without error (python3)

Tags: python, cygwin, qt5, pyqt5

I'm trying to implementate a solution provided at [Take a screenshot via a python script. [Linux]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645/take-a-screenshot-via-a-python-script-linux][1]) in a python script:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
app = QApplication([])
screen = app.primaryScreen()
screenshot = screen.grabWindow(QApplication.desktop().winId())
screenshot.save('/tmp/screenshot.png')
```

When running this code python just stops working without spawning an error.

```
BTO-user@BTO /srcpython/fod
Python 3.2.5 (default, Jul 28 2014, 01:44:48)
[GCC 4.8.3] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

BTO-user@BTO /srcpython/fod
```

The module PyQt5 is installed, but these are .dll files. Normally when I install a module there should be source files. These dll files should be a binding to Qt5 and I installed this via the cygwin dev installer. Probably something is incorrect with 1 of these 2 installations, but I tried already many re-installs. It bugs me there is not a single error report.

Comment: Do you have to do this on cygwin? I would expect the windows version to work.

Comment: Same error in windows cmd:

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\BTO-user>python3.2m
Python 3.2.5 (default, Jul 28 2014, 01:44:48)
[GCC 4.8.3] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

C:\Users\BTO-user>

(I don't know how to paste this nicely)

Comment: I mean windows python, `python3.2m` is the cygwin python. Or is it that you have to use cygwin python?

Comment: That seems indeed to make a difference.

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->


C:\Python33>python.exe
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:03:43) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (In
tel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more  information.
>>> from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWidgets'
>>

<!-- end snippet -->

Althought the QtWidgets.dll is in the repository?

Comment: cygwin is not a package manager for windows, they are two separate things. You need to install pyqt again on windows.

Comment: The initial question is solved but still the thing still refuses working. Do mark this as solved and open an new one? Or?

C:\cygwin\bin\TIP\srcpython\fod>C:\Python33\python.exe fod.py
test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fod.py", line 14, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I find many related questions on stackoverflow but no solution at this moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion from @simonzack lead to the solution. I ran the command in the cygwin environment, but after it ran in the normal windows environment it gave more descriptive (more or less) errors.

[The error about the DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found is solved by a combination of actions:

- be sure to take the last possible version http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt5/
- add to the environmentvariable path the repository of the PyQt5 installation of the windowsversion of pythong and the repository of the Qt5 installation in windows
  ]