# ImageGrab alternative in linux

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, imagegrab

I am following this tutorial which interacts with the screen but is done for Windows OS since ImageGrab is not available in linux

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2
import time

def screen_record():
    last_time = time.time()
    while(True):
        # 800x600 windowed mode
        printscreen =  np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,40,800,640)))
        print('loop took {} seconds'.format(time.time()-last_time))
        last_time = time.time()
        cv2.imshow('window',cv2.cvtColor(printscreen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

Is there any alternative for ImageGrab or is better to switch OS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Take a screenshot via a python script. \[Linux\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645/take-a-screenshot-via-a-python-script-linux)

Comment: Does pb.get_from_drawable(w,w.get_colormap(),0,0,0,0,sz[0],sz[1]) give the same output that ImageGrab?

Comment: No, that gives you a GdkPixbuf. It's easy to convert it to a numpy array though.

Comment: Then I dont see how it is duplicated

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the [pyscreenshot](https://github.com/ponty/pyscreenshot) library. It's the ImageGrab replacement for linux systems.

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
im = ImageGrab.grab()
im2 = np.asanyarray(im)
```

Hope this will work fine for your code.

Comment: Yes but before you need to do .....pip install pyscreenshot....on your terminal

Comment: Ubuntu 22 has a problem, it grabs, yes, but shows a window to allow to share the image with the script...