# Can I do 'screenshot' of image on the Python Tkinter Canvas and save it in the file?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I made program to make images in Python tkinter Canvas, but I have no idea how to save images I created. It can be png, gif, anything, but I want to save my work!

This is my code:

```
import tkinter

from PIL import Image, ImageGrab

paint = tkinter.Tk()
paint.title('paint')
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(paint, width=1100, height=1000, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()



def capture(event):
    x0 = canvas.winfo_rootx()
    y0 = canvas.winfo_rooty()
    x1 = x0 + canvas.winfo_width()
    y1 = y0 + canvas.winfo_height()

    im = ImageGrab.grab((100, 0, 1100, 1000))
    im.save('mypic.png')

canvas.mainloop()
```

I deleted some of my code because it isn't important.
But it makes a screenshot without my canvas!

Comment: You can find the canvas coordinate and then take a screenshot using `PIL`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will find out about what is PIL.

Comment: How will `capture()` get triggered, there is no code that calls the function. Why are you passing `(100, 0, 1100, 1000)`, it should be dynamic, so use `(x0, y0, x1, y1)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there is no code provided, I will give you an example on how this is done. By default there is no methods within tkinter that does this for you. So for taking screenshots, we will use `PIL`.

- Start by installing `PIL`:

```
pip install Pillow
```

- The code is as follows:

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab

root = Tk()

def capture():
    x0 = canvas.winfo_rootx()
    y0 = canvas.winfo_rooty()
    x1 = x0 + canvas.winfo_width()
    y1 = y0 + canvas.winfo_height()
    
    im = ImageGrab.grab((x0, y0, x1, y1))
    im.save('mypic.png') # Can also say im.show() to display it

canvas = Canvas(root,bg='red')
canvas.pack(padx=10,pady=10)

e = Entry(root)

canvas.create_window(canvas.canvasx(100),canvas.canvasy(100),window=e)

Button(root,text='Click a pic',command=capture).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Nothing too complicated, the coordinates work as follows `ImageGrab.grab((left,upper,right,lower))`, here is an image that might help you understand the sides better:

[image]

**Note(as per WinEunuuchs2Unix): `ImageGrab` is not supported with Linux, for alternatives use [ImageGrab alternative in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43636492/13382000)**

---

**Update(as per Carsten Fuchs): `ImageGrab` is now supported with Linux, might want to update the library first**

Comment: I tried that, but i made a screenshot of screen, without my Tkinter Canvas.

Comment: @dominikfindeisen You should update your question with the code for canvas you are using.

Comment: I added my code, but not all, without a part which is 
responsible for drawing.

Comment: @dominikfindeisen I have already commented the mistake.

Comment: I found out something about this, and I think it can be problem of availability.

Comment: Perhaps you can confirm and then update the answer to state `ImageGrab.grab()` doesn't work in Linux. For example I'm researching `wxd` for X11 Linux based systems. Previously I used `Gdk.pixbuf_get_from_window` but that is painfully slow (in computer terms).

Comment: @CoolCloud Even though I can't use answer on Linux, up vote for edit effort :)

Comment: According to https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/ImageGrab.html `ImageGrab.grab()` also works on X11 / Linux.

Comment: I’ve just added this to my own little application running on macOS, and it works perfectly. Thanks.