# Python automatic screenshot, no screen grabbing. Linux / Unix / OS X only

Tags: python, linux, screenshot

Is there a way tell python script to take a screenshot automatically and save it to desktop? All I am finding is great stuff on here, but it all seems to prompt to grab a selection after executing the script. I have found at least 5 pages on stackoverflow and none were automatic. 
Thanks

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyscreenshot Features: Capturing the whole desktop (then save it) in 3 lines: `import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab; 
    im = ImageGrab.grab();
    im.save('screenshot.png')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Take a screenshot via a python script. \[Linux\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645/take-a-screenshot-via-a-python-script-linux)

Comment: no, that didn't help, already saw that page

Comment: `os.system("import -window root ~/Desktop/screenshot.png")`? ..(there's so many ways to do this it's almost subjective)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick on a mac (unix).

```
import os
os.system("screencapture screenshot.jpg")
```

You can read more here:

http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/11/take-screen-shots-terminal-mac-os-x/

And for linux this would do the trick:

```
import os
os.system("gnome-screenshot --file=screenshot.png")
```

For further gnome-screenshot commands type:
`gnome-screenshot --help`

Comment: I know this works, but still waiting for me to grab the area and then It will screenshot it

Comment: Updated command, --window should be default. Hopefully it works now.

Comment: Still same issue, I am not sure what it is, but its always waiting for me to select the area for screenshot,. I will test it on different linux systems, thanks tho

Comment: What happens if you press prnt screen on your keyboard? Just an idea: Send the prnt screen key via python ? :)

Comment: Don't have prnt on macbook :D but will test it on classic keyboard at home :)

Comment: ah its a mac then I know why. Hang on!

Comment: Hopefully works now. Updated your title to reflect OS X also.

Comment: Oh Its a Mac hardware but running linux on it :) But would like to possibly run my py scripts on mac as well