# PIL: ImageGrab.grab() failed - OSError: screen grab failed

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a script that is constantly taking screenshots via PIL ImageGrab. Code looks like this:

```
def updateScreenshot(self):
        self.screen = ImageGrab.grab()
```

The `updateScreenshot()` function is called pretty often, like 2-3 times a second. The script was running fine until i refactored the class and moved all the screenshot related code to an external model class that encapsulates all the screenshot logic. Now my mainclass has:

```
self.screenshotService = ScreenshotService()
```

in it's `__init_`_ function. The ScreenshotService then fires `updateScreenshot()`. The first few attempts of `updateScreenshot()` still work, after that the following error occurs:

```
File "...\screenshotService.py", line 15, in updateScreenshot
    self.screen = ImageGrab.grab()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageGrab.py", line 31, in grab
    size, data = grabber()
```

I found:

1. https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1601
2. [Take a screenshot via a python script. [Linux]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645/take-a-screenshot-via-a-python-script-linux)

but these dont really point me in the right direction.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Python 3.4,
PIL: 5.4.1

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. did you find the solution for this?. Thanks.