# How to convert a word docx to an image using python

Tags: python-3.x, docx

I have a word document that I will need to convert to an image. Basically opening the doc and taking a screencap of its content. Is there any library to do this?

For example:
[image]

Comment: Based on your approach, look into spawning a subprocess for 'opening the doc'.  The 'taking a screencap' portion may be OS dependent (pyautogui vs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645/take-a-screenshot-via-a-python-script-on-linux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will do most of the work. It opens Word, loads the document, takes a screenshot, then closes Word. It maximizes Word and the screenshot is the entire screen. You will probably need to do additional image processing to get the region you want.

```
import win32com.client as win32
import pyautogui
import win32gui
import time

docfile = 'D:/test.docx'
shotfile = 'D:/shot.png'

def windowEnumerationHandler(hwnd, top_windows):
    top_windows.append((hwnd, win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)))
    
word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
word.Visible = True
word.WindowState = 1  # maximize

top_windows = []
win32gui.EnumWindows(windowEnumerationHandler, top_windows)

for i in top_windows:  # all open apps
   if "word" in i[1].lower(): # find word (assume only one)
       try:
          win32gui.ShowWindow(i[0],5)
          win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(i[0])  # bring to front
          break
       except:
          pass
    
doc = word.Documents.Add(docfile) # open file

time.sleep(2)  # wait for doc to load

myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot() # take screenshot
myScreenshot.save(shotfile) # save screenshot

# close doc and word app
doc.Close()
word.Application.Quit()
```